# What is the negation of each of the following statement?

Tags: propositional-calculus

1. Points R,S and T are collinear and T is not a point on the centered at R with radius RS
   Negation: 
   Points R,S and T are not collinear and T is a point on the center at R with radius RS

is this correct?

1. Given a line l and a point P that is not on l, there is exactly one line through P that is parallel to l
   Negation:
   Given a line l and a point p that is on l, the is at least one line through P that is not parallel to l

is this correct? Thank you

Comment: Tip: You may both upvote helpful answers, and/or accept one answer for each question you ask: to accept an answer: click on the greyed out $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer. To "upvote" an answer, click on the greyed-out "up-arrow" right above the answer's vote count (left of answer). Both upvoting and accepting answers are ways of "thanking" the answerer(s), and accepting an answer rewards both you and the answerer, with additional points.

Answer (score 1):

Re (1), NO. The negation of a proposition of the form $A$ *and* $B$ is *either not*-$A$ *or not*-$B$ (and not *not*-$A$ *and not*-$B$).

Re (2), NO. For a start the negation of *there is exactly one F* is *there are either no F's or more than one F*.

There are interesting issues lurking in the background in the second case about how to construe the *Given ...* construction, but we can probably ignore them here.

Comment: Perhaps "Given $A$ and $B$" means $\forall A\,\forall B$

Comment: For more on negations of compound statements, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws.

Answer (score 0):

Not correct, to negative and statement negate both sides and use or instead of maintaining and.

($A$ and $B)^{n}$ = ($A^{n}$ or $B^{n}$)

($A$ or $B)^{n}$ = ($A^{n}$ and $B^{n}$)